# Отображение других select-ов при выборе пункта в select-е

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

Имеются 4 select-а:

```
<select name="sel1" id="i1">
    <option value="1">Значение 1</option>
    <option value="2">Значение 2</option>
</select>
<select name="sel2" id="i2">
    <option value="1">Значение 3</option>
    <option value="2">Значение 4</option>
</select>
<select name="sel3" id="i3">
    <option value="1">Значение 5</option>
    <option value="2">Значение 6</option>
</select>
<select name="sel4" id="i4">
    <option value="1">Значение 5</option>
    <option value="2">Значение 6</option>
</select>
```

При выборе "Значение 1" в select с id `i1` должен появляться select с id `i4`.
При выборе "Значение 2" в select с id `i1` должен появляться select с id `i2`.
При выборе "Значение 3" в select с id `i2` должен появляться select с id `i3`.

Как это реализовать с помощью JS/jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Опишу простой алгоритм того как это можно сделать. А дальше сами думайте, что нужно включать и выключать именно вам

```js
// выбираем все элементы, с которыми будем работать
let sel1 = document.querySelector('#i1'),
    sel2 = document.querySelector('#i2'),
    sel3 = document.querySelector('#i3'),
    sel4 = document.querySelector('#i4');

// слушаем изменение значения нужного элемента
// в данном случае это элемент sel1, а наблюдаем мы
// за событием change
sel1.addEventListener('change', function(){
  // проверяем, если элемент sel1 сейчас
  // имеет значение "1"
  if (sel1.value === '1') {
    // переключаем состояние других элементов
    // например нужно включить sel2
    sel2.style.display = 'inline-block';
  } else if (sel1.value === '2') {
    // выключаем другой элемент, например sel2
    sel2.style.display = 'none';
  }
});
```

```html
<select name="sel1" id="i1">
 <option value="1">Значение 1</option>
 <option value="2">Значение 2</option>
</select>

<select name="sel2" id="i2">
 <option value="1">Значение 3</option>
 <option value="2">Значение 4</option>
</select>

<select name="sel3" id="i3">
 <option value="1">Значение 5</option>
 <option value="2">Значение 6</option>
</select>

<select name="sel4" id="i4">
 <option value="1">Значение 5</option>
 <option value="2">Значение 6</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!
Хоть разобрался, как работает)

Answer (score 1):

Если привязки (по какому `option`-у показывать какой `select`) сделать в вёрстке с помощью data-атрибутов, то JS код можно сделать универсальным (который без каких-либо изменений сможет с тем же успехом работать хоть на 100 `select`-ах).

В чем состоит идея: при смене выбранного значения в `select`-e скрываются `select`-ы, которые показывались при старом значении, после чего отображается нужный `select`, выбранный по новому значению. Связность `select`-ов вычисляется по `data-id` у их `option`-ов.

Исходный пример с 4 `select`-ами:

```js
$("select").on("change", function() {
  var $selectedOption = $(this).find(":selected");
  var $otherOptions = $(this).find(":not(:selected)");
  hideSubSelects($otherOptions);
  var nextSelectId = $selectedOption.data("id");
  if (nextSelectId != null) {
    var $nextSelect = $("#" + nextSelectId);
    resetSelect($nextSelect);
    $nextSelect.removeClass("hidden");
  }
});

function hideSubSelects($options) {
  $options.each(function() {
    var selectId = $(this).data("id");
    if (selectId != null) {
      var $select = $("#" + selectId);
      $select.addClass("hidden");
      hideSubSelects($select.find("option"));
    }
  });
}

function resetSelect($select) {
  $select.prop("selectedIndex", -1);
}

resetSelect($("#i1"));
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<select name="sel1" id="i1">
  <option value="1" data-id="i4">Значение 1</option>
  <option value="2" data-id="i2">Значение 2</option>
</select>
<select name="sel2" id="i2" class="hidden">
  <option value="1" data-id="i3">Значение 3</option>
  <option value="2">Значение 4</option>
</select>
<select name="sel3" id="i3" class="hidden">
  <option value="1">Значение 5</option>
  <option value="2">Значение 6</option>
</select>
<select name="sel4" id="i4" class="hidden">
  <option value="1">Значение 7</option>
  <option value="2">Значение 8</option>
</select>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

И другой список `select`-ов с тем же JS кодом:

```js
$("select").on("change", function() {
  var $selectedOption = $(this).find(":selected");
  var $otherOptions = $(this).find(":not(:selected)");
  hideSubSelects($otherOptions);
  var nextSelectId = $selectedOption.data("id");
  if (nextSelectId != null) {
    var $nextSelect = $("#" + nextSelectId);
    resetSelect($nextSelect);
    $nextSelect.removeClass("hidden");
  }
});

function hideSubSelects($options) {
  $options.each(function() {
    var selectId = $(this).data("id");
    if (selectId != null) {
      var $select = $("#" + selectId);
      $select.addClass("hidden");
      hideSubSelects($select.find("option"));
    }
  });
}

function resetSelect($select) {
  $select.prop("selectedIndex", -1);
}

resetSelect($("#i1"));
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<select id="i1">
  <option value="1" data-id="i1_1">Значение 1</option>
  <option value="2" data-id="i1_2">Значение 2</option>
</select>
<select id="i1_1" class="hidden">
  <option value="1" data-id="i1_1_1">Значение 1_1</option>
  <option value="2" data-id="i1_1_2">Значение 1_2</option>
</select>
<select id="i1_1_1" class="hidden">
  <option value="1">Значение 1_1_1</option>
  <option value="2">Значение 1_1_2</option>
</select>
<select id="i1_1_2" class="hidden">
  <option value="1">Значение 1_2_1</option>
  <option value="2">Значение 1_2_2</option>
</select>
<select id="i1_2" class="hidden">
  <option value="1" data-id="i1_2_1">Значение 2_1</option>
  <option value="2" data-id="i1_2_2">Значение 2_2</option>
</select>
<select id="i1_2_1" class="hidden">
  <option value="1">Значение 2_1_1</option>
  <option value="2">Значение 2_1_2</option>
</select>
<select id="i1_2_2" class="hidden">
  <option value="1">Значение 2_2_1</option>
  <option value="2">Значение 2_2_2</option>
</select>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```